# Query 100 million rows in MariaDB without running out of RAM (PowerBI)

Tags: configuration, powerbi, mariadb, ram

I have Windown computer with 16 GB of RAM and about 100 million rows of data. When querying "select * from table" in the cmd all the ram is used up and I see a "client run out of memory" error. I have been trying to tweak the MariaDB configuration but have not suceeded in making much progress.

I do not need to store/display the data. Ultimatly I have connected my database to PowerBI and am trying to visualize the data there. Import mode is retuning time out error after 5 hours (I have premium per user) and direct query is returning "visual exceeded the available recourses... More details: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed. Timeout value: 225 sec." Even if I can figure out how to increase timeout value with MariaDB it would take too long. I am nervous about using incremental refresh since I will not be able to download the report and make real changes and because the initial refresh will still time out.

How do people deal with having 100 million+ rows of data in their report? What type of database and connection are they using?

Any tips are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Incremental refresh is built on top of partitioning.  So the refresh will queries will be sent one per partition, and you can [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-evaluation-configuration#in-power-bi-desktop) the parallelism.

Best practice with Incremental Refresh is to keep your report and your Dataset in separate .pbix files, so you can download the report .pbix, and you don't have to do a full refresh after every change.

And to set the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters in your dataset .pbix to a small range for desktop testing.  The incremental refresh policy is only run when refreshing in the Power BI Service.

Comment: I do not see query folding so I am not sure incremental refresh will work with MariaDB. Regardless I am not sure I understand your answer. One pbix file should be connected to the data source and another is a report which points to the other pbix data source? I still would not be able to make changes in PowerQuery though, correct?

Comment: Your reports would be connected to your alread-deployed dataset.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets  And if Query Folding doesn't work (I think it does), that just means that you need to inject the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters directly into a raw SQL query.

Comment: Got it, so I should make all data transformations in Power Query before hand and I can add caluculated columns and measures after. I set up incremental refresh and I have been experimenting with parallelism configurations as you suggested but I have not had a lot of success. How do I pick optimal values for maximum number of simultaneous evaluations, available memory per evaluation and maximum number of concurrent jobs so that the initial refresh for incremental refresh does not timeout and also does not overwhelm my system? Thank you so much!

Comment: Incremental refresh only takes effect on the Power BI service.  On Power BI Desktop, it just loads the data you specify in the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I am trying to set up partitioning and configure the parallelism as you originally suggested, How do I do this? I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-xmla but I am working with SQL Server Express and I do not have Premium capacity and I would not like to purchase further subscriptions.

Comment: Custom partitioning is only available in Premium capacities.  Incremental Refresh works on Pro workspaces, though.

Comment: Thanks! I though "Premium Capacity" meant purchasing a capacity, not just a premium account. Here are the steps I took for anyone else dealing with this:
1) Add a filter at the end of data transformation: (each Parameter1) with Parameter1 = false
2) Set up incremental refresh policy
3) Publish to PowerBI and refresh. This refresh creats the partitions
4) In the dataset settings in PowerBI Service, switch Parameter1 = True
5) In Tabular editor connect to the PowerBI dataset and edited the partitions if too big
6) In SSMS connect to PowerBI dataset and manually process each parition